# jdk 1.6.0_23 does not run applet or console with firefox 3.6.15

Tags: applet, java-6, browser-plugin, firefox3.6

I have the following Problem:

I am using a newly installed Version of JDK 1.6.0_23 and Firefox 3.6
to run Applets which successfully execute on IE7.
OS is WinXP

One of the following happens depending on the Applet:
1. The Applet Canvas is Black and nothing happens.
2. The Browser asks for the missing Plugin.

I have copied the np*.dll files from the above Java installations to the
Firefox plugin directory allready.

After enabling the Java Console it is showing correctly in IE7
but does not appear when executing an Applet in Firefox.

It seems as if the Firefox Plugin is unable to access the corresponding Java installation.

Comment: Belongs on http://www.superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

One of the latest versions of Mozilla Firefox had problems with Java Applets, make sure you're not using 3.6.14.
http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Mozilla-patches-Java-applet-problems-in-Firefox-1202991.html

Comment: The Firefox Version used is 3.6.15

Comment: It's really weird that the java plugin does not show up in Firefox, you might want to try reinstalling java. Is the plugin enabled in the Firefox options? Also, I'm guessing your Windows XP is 32b, because Firefox might have problems if you're using the 64 bit version of Java.